# Update field in a table based on the same field from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables. One named "instruction" and the other named "message".

Both of these tables contain a "inactive" field which is a boolean.

In the instruction table there is also a metadata field that contains "message_id" (This is the id of the unique record in the message table).

The message table already had the inactive field setup and the relevant records are either 1 for true or 0 for false. E.g. 1 If inactive or 0 if active.

I have also added the same field to the instruction table. I am trying to update the inactive field on this table based on the value of the inactive field in the message table, through the use of the message_id. Preferably through Ruby. How would I go about this?

I understand that through the use of the message_id I have access to the message table. However, I don't understand how to update the inactive field based on the inactive field in the other table.

Comment: If you could add tables' definitions along with some sample data the question would be **much** cleaner.

Comment: share your existing code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, I can understand your models files are something like this:

Instruction

```
class Instruction
  belongs_to :message
end
```

Message:

```
class Message
  has_many :instructions
end
```

My suggested solution for your problem is using the callbacks of rails, in this case I would choose the `after_save` callback. You can also find other interesting callback here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html, hope it helps:

```
class Message
  has_many :instructions
 
  after_save :update_instructions_inactiveness, if: -> { inactive_changed? }

  def update_instructions_inactiveness
    instructions.update_all(inactive: self.inactive) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I needed to first of all set up my relations properly and the method detailed above was absolutely required. Appreciate it.